# WPF Style Sheets and Bindings

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a style sheet that i want to be used on different custom controls. 
Example
**Stylesheet.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Style x:Key="ExampleProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Border DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Background="{Binding Path=Example_BG}">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Track" >
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#FF1B9AF1" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I use something like above on the style sheet it doesn't bind to the custom control....

Is there anyway to bind stylesheet styles to work with many custom controls?

Comment: Is it your own custom control?

Comment: Yes , Its my own custom controls

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say _"bind stylesheet styles to work with many custom controls"_. Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use styles from a stylesheet. I want to data bind them to the controls the styles get assigned to. 

So if i have Textbox1 on Form1 and textbox2 on Form2
And they use the same style (Example_style from example.xaml)
How can i data bind Example_style's Background to work on each form?

Comment: @ArcSet do you want to have one style/template which uses different background? In the sample above what is `Example_BG`?

Comment: Example_BG is a color in this case. But the thing to note is its a binding. I know i could leave out Background and i could just set it on the form. BUT i want Example_BG to be set by a Data Binding instead of on the xaml on the sheet

I was wondering is there away to make a binding relative according to the form that style is used on

Such as Example_BG on Form1 could be Green and Form2 Red by using data bindings